# Тема магистерской работы

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Мне необходимо выбрать тему магистерской работы, хотелось бы что-то связанное с разработкой под Android. Подскажите что-нибудь актуальное и  интересное. Спасибо.

Comment: вот с научным руководителем и выбирайте.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать взять за идею какой-нибудь из проектов на курсах обучения типа [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com), [Udacity](http://udacity.com) или расписанный в книгах по Android (типа приложения для вызова такси) и расширить его.

Также неплохим вариантом можно посмотреть репозитории на [github](https://github.com) и поучаствовать в каком-нибудь open source проекте, внеся свой вклад в развитие сообщества и добавить весомую строчку в портфолио.